# How to load extjs 3.4 store with JSON data array

Tags: javascript, json, extjs3

I am new to extjs and have run into some issues. I have a JSON store that takes my sample data from an AJAX request to populate comboboxes. My problem is, part of the data is such that it is no displaying the way I want it.

I figure I need to use some sort of load event or function to sort through the data and populate it accordingly. Below is a sample of the data and what output I would like.

Sample JSON Data:

```
[{"year": "2013","month":["01","02","03","04","07"]}]
```

My combo box needs to display the month, each as a separate selection options.

```
01
02
03
04
07
```

I hope I explained this well, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to grab the store and call the [loadData](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData) function.

```
var store = Ext.getStore('storeId');
store.loadData(arr.month)
```

or even shorter:

```
Ext.getStore('storeId').loadData(arr.month)
```

Comment: I am able to load data fine, but it is not in the correct format. Currently the data loads like the following in a single line rather than in the original post.

    01,02,03,04,07

Comment: Is it space separated? If so, you could use `data.split(' ')` to split your data into an array and then load it into the store. Maybe try `Ext.decode(response.responseText)` will change your JSON code to a JS object.